# CSS Position: fixed and background-attachment: fixed

Tags: html, css

I have my `<footer>` set to `background-attachment: fixed` but that leaves my `<p>` tags scrolling normally. If I set `position: fixed` to my `<p>` tags, they jump to the top of the page. Is there any way to do the same thing as `background-attachment: fixed` with the `<p>` tags? I tried `position: absolute` but that results in the same thing as `position: fixed`.

Comment: Please post all the relevant code,also, you can use http://jsfiddle.net to show us what's happening.

Comment: Hi, this is your first post. So if I may point out for future use please post some of your related code. Explain what you have tried. And if you have the site hosted somewhere, post that link. And ideally create a sample where we can edit it like jsfiddle or [codepen](http://codepen.io/)

Answer (score 0):

If your question is concerning your footer interfering with your `<p>` tags, you could try setting the `background-attachment: fixed` in your body css, instead of your footer css.

For example:

```
body    { background-image:url('../images/background.jpg'); background-attachment: fixed; }
```

As for Fixed vs Absolute:

> Absolute: The element is positioned relative to its first positioned
>   (not static) ancestor element.
>
> Fixed:    The element is positioned relative to the browser window